# Using the Next.Js App Router, how can I submit a form on one page and pass the form results as arguments in a function on another page?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

**Context**
I am working on a Next.JS project (App router). It is vaguely similar to a travel booking website, such as Skyscanner. On my home page (home.js), I have a form. Submitting the form will automatically redirect to a results page (results.js). My results page features a function which makes a call to my python backend - the output of this function enables the page content to be shown. However, it requires arguments (which are in the jsonified-output of the form). Note, both pages are server page (although the form is a client-side component), and I would like to avoid changing either page to "use client".

**Question**
I would like to be able to access the form values on results.js as soon as it starts building. How best can I achieve this?

**What I've Tried**
I have tried passing the arguments through to the URL (e.g. using useRouter), but would like to avoid this since one of my arguments is the users' current location, which I would rather keep private.
I also considered using React Context API - but Next.JS documentation says this is [no longer supported in server components](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the results page have a unique ID in the url you can use to pull the data?

Comment: One way is to use Next.js session management with cookies or server-side storage mechanisms. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies

Or use `useContext` or `Redux`

Comment: Thanks for answering! I would like to avoid having a unique ID in the results URL. Are you suggesting encoding my parameters to make the unique ID, then decoding them when on the results page to extract the correct data?

I had a look at using cookies, but can't do so in my form since it is marked as "use client". useContext looks promising, but I'm then not sure I can use it in my server component (results.js).

I will now look into Redux. Please let me know if you think I've misunderstood anything

Comment: I think if your form submits to a database with a unique ID, you can use that id with useRouter and dynamic routes from Nextjs to obtain the information from that page. What if someone goes back to that page after 1 week? Will their data still be there?

Comment: @Lloukas I see what you're saying, but I think for my use case for now I wouldn't want people to be able to go back to the same results page. For now I'd rather they submitted another query.. I figured out how to solve my issue using the experimental "server actions", I'll answer my question to clarify this. Thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out a solution for this question. It involves using "server actions" (currently still an experimental feature in Next.js).
I created a file marked "use server", which exported a server function. That function took an argument, created cookies from it, then redirected to my results page.
I then called this server function as a result of my form submission on my client "home" page, with my jsonified form data as the argument. I could then access the relevant cookie on my "results" page.
Hope this helps someone :)